# Vector. Buscar el numero mayor y el del medio de un array con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo que buscar el numero mayor y el del medio de un array. Aca esta mi codigo, no se que estoy haciendo mas. El que pueda ayudarme estaria agradecida.

```js
      var vec=[];
      var mayor=0;
      var medio=0;
      for (x=0;x<=4;x++) {
       vec[x]=parseInt(prompt('Ingrese un numero'));
       if (vec[x]>mayor) {
        mayor=vec[x];
       }
       if (mayor<=medio) {
        mayor=medio;
       }
      }
      document.write("El numero mayor es: ");
      document.write(vec);
      document.write('<br>');
      document.write("El numero medio es: ");
      document.write(medio);
```

Comment: ¿Buscas el valor "promedio"?

Comment: Por qué " document.write("El numero mayor es: "); document.write(vec);"? No se supone que el valor mayor lo almacenas en "mayor"? Igualmente, no especificas que problema te da el código.. nos ayuda a buscar una solución

Answer (score 2):

Para calcular valores máximos y mínimos puedes hacerlo de forma sencilla con [Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/max).
Para calcular el promedio simplemente sumas los elementos recorriendo el array y divides por el número de elementos.

```js
var a_num = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 23];

//valores max y min
var max = Math.max(...a_num);
var min = Math.min(...a_num);

document.writeln(max);
document.writeln(min);

var sum = 0; var prom = 0;
for( var i = 0; i < a_num.length; i++ ){
  sum += a_num[i];
}
prom = sum/a_num.length;
document.writeln(prom);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apoyándome en tu código he programado lo siguiente:

```js
var vec=[];
var mayor=0;
var medio=0;
for (x=0;x<=4;x++) {
  vec[x]=parseInt(prompt('Ingrese un numero'));
  if (vec[x]>mayor) {
    mayor=vec[x];
  }
  if (mayor<=medio) {
    mayor=medio;
  }
}
document.write('La secuencia introducida es: ');
document.write(vec);
document.write('<br>');
document.write("El numero mayor es: ");
document.write(mayor);
document.write('<br>');

vec.sort((a, b) => a - b);
var longitud = vec.length;
longitud = longitud/2;
posicion_numero_medio = Math.floor(longitud)

document.write("El numero medio es: ");
document.write(vec[posicion_numero_medio]);
```

Tenías varios fallitos, además de una manera errónea de tratar de encontrar el valor que queda en **medio**.

Para empezar no mostrabas correctamente el número **mayor**, lo tenías calculado pero en vez de imprimir este imprimías el `array`:

```
document.write("El numero mayor es: ");
document.write(mayor);
```

Dentro del propio bucle, tratando de hacer algo parecido a una ordenación por el método burbuja, no encontré manera de sacar el valor que queda en el **medio**, por lo que he tenido que apoyarme en un par de funciones de **Javascript**:

Lo primero que hago es ordenar el array de menor a mayor, para el caso daría lo mismo si fuese a la inversa porque lo que nos interesa es el número que queda en medio tras ordenarse por uno de estos dos criterios. Para ello usé la función `sort()`:

```
vec.sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

Tras tener el `array` ordenado lo que necesitaba obtener era la posición del dato que quedase en mitad del `array` (en este caso al tratarse de un `array` con 5 elementos lo que necesitaba era que me devolviese un 2, ya que el `array` al comenzar por la posición **0** el número que queda en medio sería el **2**:

```
vec[2] = 'Número que queda en el centro del array';
```

Para obtenerlo usé la propiedad `length` del array para calcular su número de elementos y este lo dividí entre 2 redondeando hacia la unidad y hacia abajo:

```
longitud = longitud/2;
posicion_numero_medio = Math.floor(longitud)
```

Con este número ya podía acceder al `array` y a la posición intermedia de este:

```
document.write("El numero medio es: ");
document.write(vec[posicion_numero_medio]);
```

Como añadido comentar que esto funcionaría con un `array` de elementos **impares**, ya que en uno de elementos **pares** no existe un elemento que quede justo en el medio del `array`.

**EDIT**

Editado para forzar una ordenación numérica con el método `sort()` ya que este realiza una ordenación por el número de caracter **UNICODE** si no se le indica lo contrario.